# Extending XFS filesystem CentOS 7 Google Cloud

Tags: centos, disk, xfs

I have Googled everything, and literally nothing is working.  Here is `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        10G  7.7G  2.4G  77% /
devtmpfs        103G     0  103G   0% /dev
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           103G  8.3M  103G   1% /run
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            21G     0   21G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Yes, I've tried `xfsgrow_fs`.  It does nothing.  I've tried `parted`.  The `resize` option is not available.  You name it; I've tried it.  At this point, I think it's impossible to extend `/dev/sda1`.  My disk size is 32 GB.  I have no idea why `tmpfs` is showing 103 G.  I don't know what `tmpfs` is, and I don't have any disks larger than 32 GB on GCloud project.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `fdisk -l` please?